# How to follow $n=m$ from $(t-a)^n p(t)=(t-a)^m q(t)$?

Tags: polynomials

Say, we have $$(t-a)^n p(t)=(t-a)^m q(t)$$ where $p, q$ are polynomials and $p(a)\neq 0 \neq q(a)$. How can we conclude that $n=m$?

I've tried: the setup implies that $$n + \deg p =m+\deg q$$ but how can we show that $\deg p = \deg q$?

Comment: The scalar $a$ is a root of multiplicity $n$ of the LHS and a root of multiplicity $m$ of the RHS, thus $m=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that $p(a),q(a)\ne0$. Suppose $n<m$. Then
$$
p(t)=(t-a)^{m-n}q(t)\implies p(a)=0.
$$